# Tool for iOS/Android application automation testing

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile, automation

I'm new to automation testing and I was looking out for the best, free and easiest (little coding is fine) that can be used for testing iOS and Android applications. (Example :Aconex application)

PS: I'm using a MAC machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appium I have personally used it for both android and iOS Automation testing and it has good support.

Try the following links it'll give you a good idea

https://appium.io/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InsDgNxWlHM

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks much! Will check it out and vote the answer